# How to handle input file validation using html form

Tags: file, input

I have try to form validation with input type file . When i try to validate attached files missing. I need to again and again upload the files in form. Anyone can share how to avoid this issues

Comment: You need to add a lot more detail. What language are you using? What library or component? What server? Are you validating on the client side or on the server side? What is the existing validation code? Why do you think it is failing?

Comment: Hi I have use CI framework, Server side validation. Im using Codeigniter validation library

Comment: Just do a first validation in client side. Obviously if the file is in the form you send for validation, there will be an upload.